# TypeScript says 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType' is not defined

Tags: typescript, eslint

In my code I have:

```js
responseType: XMLHttpRequestResponseType
```

As a function argument.

TypeScript linter in VSCode complains saying that:

```
'XMLHttpRequestResponseType' is not defined.eslintno-undef
type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = "" | "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "document" | "json" | "text"
```

What is wrong here?
It seems to find the type as it shows the type definition.

Comment: No, your linter says it's not defined. You know TypeScript is doing well here because it shows the type definition to you.